# I am trying to change font style of a specific word from word document using Spire.Doc. But code is not giving me the expected result

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, wordprocessingml, spire.doc

I am trying to change font of a specific word to Italic from word document using Spire.Doc. But code is not giving me the expected result.

Exaample -  Albia A et al [l0] and Jain M et al [3] also observed predominance of non-neoplastic lesions with few cases of adenocarcinoma.
Incidence of chronic cholecystitis was also comparable to Shah H et al [11], Terada T [12] and Zahrani IH et al [13] who encountered 82.25%, 94.1% and 96.08% cases respectively.

So, from above paragraph only 'et al' should be formatted to Italic, everything else should stay as it is.

Pasting down the code that I have tried below.

Body body = document.Body;

```
        var paragraphs = body.Descendants<Paragraph>();
        foreach (Paragraph para in paragraphs)
        {
            if (para.InnerText.Contains("et al"))
            {
                var runs = para.Descendants<Run>();                    
                if (runs != null)
                {
                    foreach (Run run in runs)
                    {                           
                        Index index = para.InnerText.IndexOf("et al");
                        para.Parent.ElementAt(index).AppendChild(new Italic());                            
                    }
                }
             }
         }
```

I am new to using Spire.Doc. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following code sample to change the font style of a specific word in a Word document:

```
using Spire.Doc;
using Spire.Doc.Documents;

namespace ChangeFontStyle
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Initialize an instance of the Document class
            Document doc = new Document();
            //Load a Word document
            doc.LoadFromFile("Input.docx");

            //Search for a specific word in the document
            TextSelection[] selection = doc.FindAllString("et al", false, true);

            //Change font style for all occurrences of the word
            foreach (TextSelection text in selection)
            {
                text.GetAsOneRange().CharacterFormat.Italic = true;
            }

            //Save the result document
            doc.SaveToFile("ChangeFontStyle.docx", FileFormat.Docx2013);
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```